# SP DVWP subtotal containing 'Yes' XPATH/XSLT question

Tags: data-view-web-part

I have a Data View Web Part with a grouping. Now I have a column that contains either 'Yes' or 'No'. I am able to count the number of 'Yes' and "No' under certain grouping, however, I would like to know if there is anyway to count only 'Yes'?

Here is what the current xslt looks like:

```
<xsl:value-of select="count($nodeset/@Status)" />
```

Again it's counting @Status under certain nodeset but I would like to count only those @Status which has value of 'Yes'.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested since I don't have your particular nodeset but it should be something similar to the following:

```
<xsl:value-of select="count($nodeset[@Status='Yes'])" />
```

The XPATH may need some work but you can put conditions within brackets like that.

Comment: Thank you awesome! Im bit new to XSLT world, thanks a lot for your help :)